# How to create two cumulative columns based off of condition output from another column?

Tags: r

I am trying to loop through my dataframe's rows and add 1 to either the Won or Loss column based off the Result column in the dataframe. I need it to print the dataframe row after every loop through the code.

I have tried to use the cumsum() function, but I need it to be conditional on the Result character(Won or Lost), but I have failed every time. I have also tried a for loop, and the closest I came to solving the issue was it printing out the new dataset with the total matches played in the Won Column.

```
for (row in 1:nrow(Dylan)) {
if( Dylan$Result == "Won") {Dylan$Won = Dylan$Won + 1}
else {Dylan$Lost = Dylan$Lost + 1}
}


Here are the errors I get:
In if (Dylan$Result == "Won") { ... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (Dylan$Result == "Won") { ... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I need the new dataframe to show the continual additions to each Won and Loss Columns, so the columns increase over the rows, and not just show the total amount of wins and total amount of losses in every row.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Does this work? `Dylan$Won <- cumsum(Dylan$Result == "Won") ; Dylan$Lost <- cumsum(Dylan$Result != "Won")`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

does this work:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(Dylan)) {
  if (Dylan$Result[row] == "Won") {
    Dylan$Won = Dylan$Won + 1
  } else {
    Dylan$Lost = Dylan$Lost + 1
  }
}
```